# Generators of a simple extension K over F

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose $K$ is a finite extension of a base field $L$ of degree $n$. Assume that $K = F (\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in K$. Consider the embeddings $\sigma_i$'s of $K$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$. (The complex embeddings are taken care of by separating the real and imaginary parts and considering them as two real embeddings.)

1. How is $\{1, \alpha,...,\alpha^{n-1} \}$ a basis for $K$ over $F$? What could be another non-trivial choice of basis? (Trivial choice here refers to scaling of these basis elements by an element of $K$)
2. In other words, can we say that $\{\sigma_1 (\alpha),...,\sigma_n(\alpha)\}$ is a basis of $K$ over $F$?
3. In another yet similar context, how does the set $\{1, \alpha,...,\alpha^{n-1} \}$ generate $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ as an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The questions are natural (+1), but I believe they are answered in most textbooks. I invite you to work this out yourself with the aid of the following remarks. 1) Another element can be used in place of $\alpha$ (but that's not all) 2) Does this work when $F=\Bbb{Q}$ and $\alpha=\sqrt2$. Is the set $\{\sigma_1(\alpha),\sigma_2(\alpha)\}$ linearly independent over $F$? 3) This may or may not be true. $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$ should be a ring. So closed under products. What goes wrong when $\alpha=\sqrt{1/2}$.

Comment: Mind you, it is a slightly non-trivial, but not exceedingly difficult result to show that in claim 2. we can always find a primitive element $\alpha$ such that this works. But it doesn't work for all the primitive elements.

Comment: For extra credit: Figure out what you need to assume about the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ for the claim 3. to be true?